# mysqli custom update function not working

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am using this function I found in a book but it seems to not work.

```
/*
Update records in the database
@param String the table
@param Array of changes field => value
@param String the condition
@return Bool
*/    
public function updateRecords($table, $changes, $condition){
    $update = " UPDATE " . $table . " SET ";
    foreach($changes as $field => $value){
        $update .=  "`" . $field . "`='{$value}',";
    }

    //remove our trailing ,
    $update = substr($update, 0, -1);
    if($condition != ""){
        $update .= " WHERE " . $condition;
    }
    $this->executeQuery($update);
    return true;
}
```

I instantiated the object as follows:

```
$a = new Mysqldb($z);
$g = $a->newConnection("localhost", "root", "secrete", "mydatabase");
```

and used the specified method as follows:

```
$a->updateRecords("members", array("id" => 10, "username" => "Paco"), " WHERE id= 10");
```

But the thing doesn't work telling me that there is an error in my syntax:

```
Fatal error: Error executing query: UPDATE members SET `id`='10',`username`='Paco' WHERE WHERE id= 10 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=10' at line 1 in C:\Users\Robert\Documents\web development\xampp\htdocs\xampp\web_development\MVC\registry\mysqldb.class.php on line 86
```

So I tried the same query directly on the command line along with the backticks and it was successful. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
$a->updateRecords("members", array("id" => 10, "username" => "Paco"), " WHERE id= 10");
```

to

```
$a->updateRecords("members", array("id" => 10, "username" => "Paco"), " id= 10");
```

It is appending `WHERE` clause twice

You are appending another `WHERE` in

```
if($condition != ""){
    $update .= " WHERE " . $condition;
}
```

which is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at your error message. It is telling you that `WHERE` appears twice in your query.

Remove the `WHERE` from the string you are passing to `$condition` in the `$a->updateRecords()` call and it should work.